# Modify contacts not working ( java.lang.NullPointerException )

Tags: android, exception, android-contacts, contactscontract, rawcontacts

I have a problem with editing contacts in Android. I'm using `contentProviderOperation` with `newUpdate`, but it's not working. It only works when the field already has something. If I have a field filled, erase it, then save and try to edit it again, I find that it's not saved and that's when I get the exception.

Here is the code I have to edit:

```
        if (emailantigo.equals("") && !email.equals("")) {
debug("email " + email);
            debug("id " + contactId);
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID, contactId)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK)
                            .withValue(
                                    ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,
                                            email).build());
        } else if (!email.equals(emailantigo)) {
debug("email " + email);
            debug("id " + contactId);
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withSelection(
                            ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID
                            + "=? AND "
                                    + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
                                    + "='"
                                            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
                                            + "'",
                                            new String[] { String.valueOf(contactId) })
                                            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE,
                                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK)
                                                    .withValue(
                                                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                                                            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,
                                                                    email).build());
        }
        try {
            cr.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    public void debug(String msg) {
            Log.i("CONTATOS", msg);
        }
```

Here is the exception I get, from LogCat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1266)
android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:160)
android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithOperationApplicationExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
android.content.ContentProviderProxy.applyBatch(ContentProviderNative.java:460)
android.content.ContentProviderClient.applyBatch(ContentProviderClient.java:95)
android.content.ContentResolver.applyBatch(ContentResolver.java:622)
```

** EDIT 2 **

found solution by myself

the partial code that works:

```
Cursor cursorEmail = cr.query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = "
                        + contactId, null, null);

        if (cursorEmail.moveToFirst()) {
            if (!email.equals(emailantigo))
                key_email = ops
                        .add(ContentProviderOperation
                                .newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                                .withSelection(
                                        ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID
                                                + "=? AND "
                                                + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
                                                + "=? AND "
                                                + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE
                                                + "=?",
                                        new String[] {
                                                String.valueOf(contactId),
                                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
                                                String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK) })
                                .withValue(
                                        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                                .withValue(
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK)
                                .withValue(
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,
                                        email).build());
        }
        cursorEmail.close();

        if (!key_email && emailantigo.equals("") && !email.equals(emailantigo)) {
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
                            String.valueOf(contactId))
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,
                            email)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK)
                    .build());
        }
```

the newInsert not works with Data._ID or Data.Contact_ID, I dont know why, must have some logic behind this, but its working now ^^ !

Obs: Not tested in synced contacts.

Comment: From the logs it seems your ``ops`` in ``cr.applyBatch(...)`` is null for some reason not visible in code snippet you provided.

Comment: Ye, I tought it, but when I edit a existing field, its works, but not work if the field exist but is empty.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ContentResolver but you might also want to make sure ``email`` or ``contactId`` are not null. Adding some ``Log.d``s should help you to find out the null parameter quickly.

Comment: Method "debug" show what i typed on fields to save it, so its not null.

Comment: the issue seems to be null pointer inside Contacts content provider , some values that you are passing maybe null, could you post the whole call stack